Xcode disable "unqualified call to 'std::move'
I have a C++ file that uses std::move a lot, and the code is a lot cleaner without having to qualify each use of std::move with std::. I added a using std::move declaration to the top of the file, but Xcode is giving me this warning that I want to turn off:

Unqualified call to 'std::move'

In the build log, I see entries like:
/Users/me/code/Proj/src/File.cpp:30:27: warning: unqualified call to 'std::move' [-Wunqualified-std-cast-call]

How do I disable that warning?

Full warning message should provide information which switch activates this warning. Adding this swithc to copilation option with no- prefix should disable warning. Something like -Wno-unqualified-std-cast-call. Anyway you should not do it, IMO this is a bad practice (that is why warning was introduced).

I see this is intended as SO knowledge sharing, but the question is very unclear. If you admit that having to qualify std::move with std:: is good, then why using std::move. Anyway, few lines of example code would explain it much better than natural language description.

@pptaszni there was a typo in the question, fixed

To suppress that warning, you'd have to add a -Wno-unqualified-std-cast-call to your C++ Other Warning flags section


You seem to a word. Or more.

Surpressings warning without knowing why you have them is a bad move (pun intended). And even when you do you should never disable them globally for a whole project.

@PepijnKramer I know why the warnings are there. The compiler provides -Wno for a reason

@sweenish

The -Wno is mostly there to be able to compile legacy code. New code should compile without warnings ;)

A good reason not to do that:  both because move is a common name and because these functions accept any values.

I'm usually very good about not filling global namespace with common names like move. std::move sees very common use and so actually in my code I'm perfectly happy to let it be std::move. I also am considering #define mv(x) std::move(x) (my intellisense also tells me I don't have a global mv defined anywhere)

Compare: GetSync( std::move( url ), std::move( success ), std::move( fail ) ); vs GetSync( mv( url ), mv( success ), mv( fail ) );
